# no aparecen todas las imagenes en el carusel de bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-carousel

Estoy usando la plantilla de carusel de bootstrap y solamente me aparecen 2 de 4 imagenes. Cuando elimino una diapositiva en el editor entonces aparecen 3. Existe una cantidad tope de diapositivas? creo que no, tal vez sea algo del tiempo que transcurre entre cada imagen/diapositiva lo que no permite ver todas las imagenes. Cree una clase carusel-content para colocarle un titulo centrado en cada imagen.

HTML:

```
<div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carusel" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="/images/depilacion.jpg" class="d-block w-100 " alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-content">
          <h1>DEPILACION</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="/images/cejas.jpg" class="d-block w-100 " alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-content">
          <h1>CEJAS</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="/images/uñas.jpg" class="d-block w-100 " alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-content">
          <h1>UÑAS</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="/images/pestañas.jpg" class="d-block w-100 " alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-content">
          <h1>PESTAÑAS</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:50%;
    left: 35%;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    font-family:'Dancing Script';;
    color: aliceblue;
    border-color:lightpink;
    border-style:groove;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    
}
.carousel-content h1 {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 100px;
    
}

  
.carousel-item img {
    height: 75vh;
    background: no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asegúrate de que utilices las mismas clases del [**Carousel Crossfade**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/#crossfade), ya que estás utilizando este tipo de carousel: **`id="carouselExampleFade"`**.

Otro posible error es que estás entrando mal a las rutas de tus imágenes (ya que indicas que algunas imágenes si se muestran pero otras no).

También podrías agregarle [**indicadores**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/#usage) para indicar cuantas imágenes vas a desplegar en el carousel de bootstrap:

```
<!-- Indicamos a "data-slide-to" que será del 0 al 3 ya que estás utilizando 4 imágenes,
si agregarás más imágenes, tendrás que añadir otro <li...></li> y así sucesivamente. -->

<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    // . . .
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. No me queda claro lo de asegurarme que utilicen las mismas clases del carousel crossfade, sin embargo, las rutas de las imagenes estan bien ya que probe colocando en el codigo solamente 3 "carousel-item" y aparecen correctamente los 3, los alterne y todos aparecen pero unicamente cuando hay 3. El 4 carousel-item no lo muestra. Tambien me di cuenta que no funcionan  los botones indicadores para avanzar o retroceder las imagenes. El codigo lo copie directamente de bootstrap..

Comment: Ah, de seguro no estás utilizando el cdn de bootstrap correctamente, que versión de bootstrap estás utilizando? mira esta [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) de bootstrap 5, o esta [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/) de bootstrap 4 e importa los cdn donde te indican.

Comment: Gracias... me voy a fijar!! muchas gracias!!

Comment: Me avisas si te funcionó.